# Modify values in a table filled with logic iterate in struts1

Tags: jsp, struts1

I've created a table with logic iterate in my jsp. Now I want that on the click on a button (edit), a column of this table become editable.

```
    <logic:iterate id="result" name="result">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;"><bean:write name="result" property="key"/></td>                   
                    <td style="border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;"><input type="text" value="<bean:write name="result" property="value"/>" style="border:none" readonly>
                    </td>                                       

                </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Who can help me?

Comment: You're asking how to write JavaScript?

Comment: Yes JavaScript or what you prefer...

Comment: What you have tried so far ?